# why not browsers mesh the page with worng html tags?

Tags: html, tags

i am working on a project using html5 properties like `<header>,<article>` etc... it's work fine.
but when i review it & saw  that i wrote `<heder></heder>` instead of `<header></header>` but the structure work well in all browsers.
so can anyone explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers don't do anything special with elements they don't recognise.

If the page didn't depend on any particular rendering of that element then replacing it with a different one (that had no default styles applied to it) wouldn't make a difference *to the visual rendering*.

Comment: thanks david for your answer but if i put an id or class in it then what happens.

Comment: @sandeep - You get an element in the DOM called "heder" with an id or class attribute on it. What did you expect to happen?